# how to select all edges between two selected nodes in cytoscape using the GUI

Tags: cytoscape

Does anyone know how to select all edges between two selected nodes in cytoscape using the GUI?

This would be easy to do manually if it were a small network but in my case there are over 10k nodes.
Ideally I want to select all edges that are between a list of 70 nodes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, much to my surprise, the answer is "no", I don't know of an easy way to select edges connecting two nodes.  I have a "hacky" way to do it that would work, though:

1. Select all of the nodes you want
2. Do **File->New Network->From Selected Nodes, All Edges**.  This will give you a new network with only the selected nodes and the edges that connect them.  Now, change the "shared interaction" column for all of those edges to something unique (e.g. Select).  This column is shared between the subnetwork you created and the original network.
3. Now, back in the original network, use can use the Filter panel to create a column filter looking for all edges with a shared interaction of "Select".  They will then be selected.

Probably much more complex than you might want, but it will do the job.  I would also recommend adding a feature request (Help->Report a Bug) for selecting edges connecting selected nodes.